# How to clean up the symbol store?

Tags: continuous-integration, symbols

We're running continuous integration builds from TFS, and generating a lot of symbol files that we store using symstore.exe (67GB worth in the last year or so.)  How do other people clean up their symbol files?  Do you automate the process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[AgeStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538002(v=vs.85).aspx) can be used for this - you can run it periodically to delete symbols from old daily builds that aren't in use anymore.  However, you need to make sure you archive your milestone or released builds that you need to keep longer since AgeStore will delete those as well.